# jquery val(); function and ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript variable there is = some html i print out from a tabel in my server.

I use the variable in the Jquery function val(); but the problems is every time a person write some content in a field something with a " sign or a ' sign. the javascript get confused.

```
var message = '<%= raw(post.content) %>';

$("button").click(function() {
  $("#somediv").val(message);
});
```

This code "<%= raw(post.content) %>" is a ruby on rails code there get the content from the content field in my post table.

Any suggestions what i can do?

Comment: Use `"<%= j post.content %>"`.  See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"<%= j post.content %>" did solve the problem, like "vee" write in the comment.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript